# Adjusting seaborn's barplot bars width

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I'm new to data analysis using python and I'm trying to create a very basic visualization of some Premier League football data. One of these visualizations is the number of corners per home team in the 2018/19 Season.

I've managed to plot the graph I'm looking for, but the names on the X-axis are all over each other and, therefore, unreadable, as seen below:
[image: As you can see, the names are not properly distributed on the X-axis]

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb

dataset = pd.read_csv("/Users/lfarias/Downloads/england-premier-league-matches-2018-to-2019-stats.csv")

dataset.columns

cantos = sb.barplot(x = 'home_team_name', y = 'home_team_corner_count', data = dataset)
cantos.tick_params(labelsize=14)
cantos.set_ylabel("Número de escanteios",fontsize=15)
cantos.set_xlabel("",fontsize=1)
```

Is there any way I can fix this?

P.S.: I've seen another question similar to the one I'm asking, but it ended up not being useful to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, it's better if you copy and paste your code in as a code block so people can copy it to run bits, and so people using screen readers can access it. Providing a minimal working example we can run is also helpful. (Remember, we don't have your data.)

Comment: Sure! I'm sorry, just getting used to Stack Overflow. I'll put my code and data in.

Comment: Of course; it's something everyone has to learn when they start!

Comment: `cantos.tick_params(labelsize=14, labelrotation=30)`

Comment: `matplotlib.pyplot.Axes.tick_params` affects both axes by default, so that should also rotate the y-axis labels. You'd need to specify `axis='x'` to just do what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate the x-tick labels; this will produce a nicer-looking plot than if you just widen the bars enough to make the text not overlap.

Just change the `rotation` value until you find an angle you like. `horizontalalignment` can also be set to `right` or `left`.

```py
cantos.set_xticklabels(cantos.get_xticklabels(), rotation = 45, horizontalalignment = 'center')
```

Comment: Seems good! However, I'm getting an error because of that "g"right before the get_xticklabels() parameter: "name g is not defined". I tried importing matplotlib, but no success so far. Am I missing something else?

Comment: oh! I thought I caught all of those; that was the name of my figure; just a sec.

Comment: So, that was just the 'calling' of the CSV, right? Cool! It worked perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: I did: `g = sns.<someplot>()`, where you called it `cantos`. I caught the one at the start of the line, but not in the paramter.